# Which one does _id point when I use it at a function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

A: Code A is clear, `_myid` in `whereSimple("$_myid = ? ",_id.toString())` means `val _myid:String=DBRecordTable._ID`

B: I confuse Code B, which one does `_id` in `whereSimple("$_id = ? ",_id.toString())` mean,  is it `val _id:String=DBRecordTable._ID` ? or is it `fun getRecordByID(_id:Long)` ?

BTW, Code C is wrong, it can't be compiled!

**Code A**

```
class DBRecordHandler(val mDBRecordHelper: DBRecordHelper =DBRecordHelper.instance,
                      val tableName:String =DBRecordTable.TableNAME,
                      val _myid:String=DBRecordTable._ID
                      ) {


      fun getRecordByID(_id:Long):MDBRecord? = mDBRecordHelper.use{
          select(tableName)
              .whereSimple("$_myid = ? ",_id.toString())
              .parseOpt{MDBRecord(HashMap(it)) }
      }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class DBRecordHandler(val mDBRecordHelper: DBRecordHelper =DBRecordHelper.instance,
                      val tableName:String =DBRecordTable.TableNAME,
                      val _id:String=DBRecordTable._ID
                      ) {


      fun getRecordByID(_id:Long):MDBRecord? = mDBRecordHelper.use{
          select(tableName)
              .whereSimple("$_id = ? ",_id.toString())
              .parseOpt{MDBRecord(HashMap(it)) }
      }
}
```

**Code C**

```
class DBRecordHandler(val mDBRecordHelper: DBRecordHelper =DBRecordHelper.instance,
                      val tableName:String =DBRecordTable.TableNAME,
                      val _id:String=DBRecordTable._ID
                      ) {


      fun getRecordByID(_id:Long):MDBRecord? = mDBRecordHelper.use{
          select(tableName)
              .whereSimple("${this._id}= ? ",_id.toString())
              .parseOpt{MDBRecord(HashMap(it)) }
      }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it out with a simple example? [https://rextester.com/AXXN71772](https://rextester.com/AXXN71772)

Comment: Thanks! you may see my added Code C, Code C is wrong, it can't be complied!

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Comment: Unresolved reference: _id

Comment: You can see it  at https://www.dropbox.com/s/eetzawsh2flt7vr/_Snipaste_2018-11-06_12-10-07.png?dl=0

Comment: Not sure why does this happen. But you may try adding a line `val myid = _id` and replace `"${this._id}= ? "` with `"$myid = ? "` to work it around if you want to keep the function parameter name as `_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "more local" version of the variable is the one that will be used, i.e. the one declared as a parameter into the function, rather than the one declared as a constructor parameter of the class.  This is called shadowing.

Note that if you ctrl+click on the variable in your code, your IDE will take you to its declaration, so you can see which instance is going to be used at any point in the code where you refer to it.